# Equivalence of two dedekind-infinite definitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition 1: A set M is infinite iff there‘s some N $\subset$ M with some f: M $\to$ N bijective (|M| = |N|).

Definition 2: A set M is infinite iff some g: M $\to$ M being injective but not surjective.

I want to prove the equivalence of both definitions. Does anyone know/see a simple proof? I wonder if one should start by writing down both definitions as PL formulas and go from there? In the comments there is a link where you can find another link with the very proof I want but as a computer program I cannot quite understand and way too complicated. I hope for a smooth and simple proof but I do not see it.

I could now see a proof from 2 to 1: Assume definition 2. Then g: M $\to$ rng(M) is bijective and because g: M $\to$ M is not surjective it means rng(M) lacks at least one element of M, so that rng(M) $\subset$ M which fullfills definition 1. Is that ok? But what with the direction from 1 to 2?

Comment: Seems like a good idea. And hint: injective functions are bijective onto their image.

Comment: Your proof of direction $2\to 1$ is correct. The other direction seems straightforward: if $f:M\to N$ is a bijection and $N\subset M$, then $ran(f)\neq M$, hence $f:M\to M$ is injective but not surjective.